# Go binary not found when using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go

I am following [Go's Docker instructions](https://blog.golang.org/docker). Their example works for me. I am now trying to modify it to run a tcp server:

```
go get github.com/Kelindar/tcp
```

Add a Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang

ADD . /go/src/github.com/Kelindar/tcp
RUN go install github.com/Kelindar/tcp

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/tcp

EXPOSE 8080
```

I then build it:

```
docker build --no-cache -t tcp .
```

build output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    322kB
Step 1/5 : FROM golang
 ---> 9fe4cdc1f173
Step 2/5 : ADD . /go/src/github.com/Kelindar/tcp
 ---> 10abce658324
Step 3/5 : RUN go install github.com/Kelindar/tcp
 ---> Running in 59dc47b30474
Removing intermediate container 59dc47b30474
 ---> 8fab53d2882c
Step 4/5 : ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/tcp
 ---> Running in 18d4b5befccb
Removing intermediate container 18d4b5befccb
 ---> 073fdb78a481
Step 5/5 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in 8ee2b7bc0cba
Removing intermediate container 8ee2b7bc0cba
 ---> 8bf9f82d4fef
Successfully built 8bf9f82d4fef
Successfully tagged tcp:latest
```

Now, I run it:

```
docker run --name test --rm tcp
```

I get an error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /go/bin/tcp: not found
```

Not really sure where to go on this.

Comment: good rule of thumb is to get your code working outside of any container first ... only after you have it up and running then put a working app inside docker ... this simplifies and reduces the range of unknowns and separates code related errors from potential errors only due to docker config unknowns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- The package `github.com/Kelindar/tcp` does not contain a `main` function, thus it can't produce a binary to be executed.
- There is no `main` package, and every go program needs a `main` package with a `main` function

Whether you run `go build` or `go install` in this repository, you will see that nothing will happen, since your package is actually a library.

Now if you add a `cmd/tcp_server` folder with a `tcp_server.go` file like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/kelindar/tcp"
)

func main() {
    closingChan := make(chan bool)
    onAccept := func(c net.Conn) {
        // Do something here.
    }

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 4242))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to net.Listen: %v", err)
    }

    server := &tcp.Server{
        Closing:  closingChan,
        OnAccept: onAccept,
    }

    log.Println("Server ready...")
    if err := server.Serve(l); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Server crashed: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("Server stopped")
}
```

And that you update your Dockerfile to use the command that uses your tcp package:

```
FROM golang

RUN go get github.com/Kelindar/tcp
RUN go build -o $GOPATH/bin/tcp_server $GOPATH/src/github.com/Kelindar/tcp/cmd/tcp_server/tcp_server.go

ENTRYPOINT tcp_server

EXPOSE 8080
```

Your server will be working properly within docker:

> `2019/06/16 05:23:29 Server ready...`

Comment: Cool. Why use go build rather than go install if you just put it in $GOPATH/bin anyway?